# mod_deflate - can't seem to get content-encoding header to be set

Tags: apache, http, mod-deflate

I am trying to set up mod_deflate to deliver compressed css/js/html content, but am having difficulty getting apache to send the 'content-encoding' header correctly.

I have tried the following, placed in my .htaccess file in the web root:

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/css application/xml

but, checking the headers using firebug, it doesn't appear to be working, even though it does on my local copy of MAMP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Apache are you using on your delivery server?  I believe the `AddOutputFilterByType` is deprecated in versions > 2.1.  However, you can still accomplish this, just a few more lines:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^" no-gzip
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.(?:css|js|html)$ !no-gzip
```

The `DEFLATE` filter, has a built-in check of the `no-gzip` environment variable.  So, this is turning on the `DEFLATE` filter, then turning it off for everything, then turning it back on for `css|js|html` files by un-setting the `no-gzip` filter for those requests.

Hope that helps.